# Using htaccess to show files from an inner directory

Tags: .htaccess

This is my local dir structure

```
-> app
  -> settings
  -> readme
  -> php
    -> the entire app code
```

Now since all my app code is in the `php/` dir, I have to do `localhost/app/php` to access my app. I would like to access the files in the `php/` dir my justing typing `localhost/app`.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!php/).*)$ php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It worked but after I removed the `RewriteBase /`. Also can you tell me what the third line is actually doing.

Comment: Sure, that rewrite rule is checking whether URI is already NOT starting with `/php/` and if not then it forwards request to `/php/$1` Here `$1` is the back reference of the captured string from match on left hand side.